# how to store a byte [] into a single variable in android/java

Tags: java, android, type-conversion, arrays

I have a `String str = "admin:admin"`

i want to convert it in the ASCII.

I have tried `str.getByte("US-ASCII");` this is returning me a byte[] array (i.e `[97, 100, 109, 105, 110, 58, 97, 100, 109, 105, 110]`). i want the ASCII value in a single String variable. how can I do this.

simple i want this String strASCII = "971001091051105897100109105110"

is this possible?

I also tried this

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i=0; i<=b.length; i++) {
        builder.append(b);
    }
    String result = builder.toString();
```

but now its returning me something like this

```
[B@405666e0[B@405666e0[B@405666e0[B@405666e0[B@405666e0[B@405666e0[B@405666e0[B@405666e0[B@405666e0[B@405666e0[B@405666e0[B@405666e0
```

what is this?

Comment: Note, though, that this value cannot be reliably converted back to the original string (e.g. does `101110` mean `10 10 10` or `101 110`?). It looks like you are building some kind of home-made weak encryption or hashing here. This is usually not necessary, since there are very good option right available in the Android library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try simply looping with `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (byte b : arr) {
    builder.append(b);
}
String result = builder.toString();
```

You could, of course, do the same thing with string concatenation, but using `StringBuilder` explicitly will be faster for lots of small appends.

Comment: plz see my edited question I tried your solution but not getting the desired result

Comment: 'arr' should be the byte[] array returned from str.getBytes("US-ASCII").

Comment: @Qadir Your code is different from mine. In order for it to work, you have to use mine (where `arr` is the array you're iterating through) or you can use `builder.append(b[i])` using your standard for loop.

Answer (score 0):

using simple for Loop and String builder we can do this also.

```
 StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        builder.append(b[i]);
    }
    String result = builder.toString();
```

Comment: I will point out that my answer is exactly the same as this one, it just uses the other loop syntax.